# Square a number to the power of an array element-wise using python loop

Tags: python, arrays, loops, for-loop

I need to square a single number to the power of a list (element wise) and append the result to a new list.

for example:

I have a list

```
 a = [1,2,3,4]
```

and a digit

```
 b = 12
```

I would like to square b to the power a (element wise) and append the result to a new list

I have tried doing this:

```
result = []
yrs = [0,1,2]
newr = 10
for u in range(len(yrs)):
    calc = (1 + newr) ** -u
    result.append(calc)
print result
```

but the loop to square to the power of the array doesn't work

Comment: What does not work. be more precies. What is the output you expect, what is the output you got, what error do you encounter, etc.

Comment: Do you understand what `range(len(yrs))` means?

Comment: the loop to square to the power of the array elementwise doesn't work

Comment: why are you adding 1 + newr ? your just need newr ** u

Comment: When you say'**square** b to the power a' do you mean '**raise** b to the power of a'?

Comment: @quamrana i need to to print a result of (1 + newr) ^ -0, (1 + newr) ^ -1, (1 + newr) ** -2 where "^" meant to the power

Comment: Its odd that when I run the code in my answer and the code you post, I get exactly the same `result`.

Comment: @quamrana That's because in the question, `range(len(yrs))` happens to be a list (a generator in python 3) containing the same items than `yrs`. The code posted in the question provides the good output by accident. Of course, unless this is actually not the good output, in which case the question and the comments aren't clear enough.

Comment: @Unatiel: Yes, I realise that, but the OP reports that it doesn't work.

Comment: @lmm Instead of "for u in range(len(yrs)):", you should do "for u in yrs:"

Answer (score 0):

It did not throw any exceptions for me maybe `-u` should be `u`?

Comment: i need it to print a result of  (1 + newr)  ^  -0, (1 + newr)  ^ -1, (1 + newr) ** -2

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
yrs = [0, 1, 2]
newr = 10
print([(1 + newr) ** -u for u in yrs])
```

Output:

[1, 0.09090909090909091, 0.008264462809917356]